Room DataBase in KMP
I have a database ( mysqlite_sampel.db), I want to put it in the files folder and use the information in it, how can I use a database that is in the files folder both in Android and iOS and ROOM and KMP?
I have a pre-populated or pre-packaged database and I want to use it in KMP by ROOM. I don't have a problem in the Android section and I can use the creatFromAsset method to enter the database in the device's memory, but for the iOS section, we don't have this method and the assets folder, what should we do?
I tried to do this using the ROOM library, but I found that there are still no versions of this library designed to be used on ios for use DB file in assets.

Room is a warpper for SQLite. See here how to use it in KMP: https://developer.android.com/kotlin/multiplatform/room -- That's not what you are asking about though, because you have a MySQL database. That has nothing to do with Room: You can either use Room or MySQL. Please [edit] your question and specify which you want to use and remove the other.

Ah, it is Room after all. From the link of my previous comment: "[...] APIs to create a RoomDatabase using an existing database (i.e. a pre-packaged database) are not available in common and are thus not available in other platforms other than Android.". And: "We intend to add support for pre-packaged databases in a future version of Room." -- You need to either wait until it is supported or populate the database manually during runtime on first startup.
